# Call member function on object pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, polymorphism, member-functions

I am trying to write a simple game in C++ and currently have my Game_Window class holding an array of pointers to game objects as follows:

```
class Game_Window {
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    int num_objects;

public: 
    char** objects;

/* The rest of the class goes here */
}
```

Inside my Game_Window class I want to define a function that calls the "print()" function on all objects held in the game window "objects" array as follows.

```
void Game_Window::print_objects() {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_objects; i++) {
        (objects[i])->print();        /* THE PROBLEM IS HERE */
    }
}
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
game_window.cpp:29:15: error: member reference base type 'char' is not a structure or union
                (objects[i])->print();
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

All objects in my game have a "print()" function so I know that's not the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have an array of `char*` pointers, not game objects or whatever you meant to have there.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. I created a class called Game_Object that all my game objects will inherit, and gave it a print() method.

```
class Game_Object {
private:
    Location location;

public: 
    Game_Object();

    Location *get_location() { return &location; }
    void print();
};

class Diver : public Game_Object {
public:
    explicit Diver(int x, int y);

};


class Game_Window {
private:
    int width;
    int height;
    int num_objects;

public: 
    Game_Object** objects;


    explicit Game_Window(int width, int height);
    ~Game_Window();

    int get_width() { return width; }
    int get_height() { return height; }
    int get_object_count() { return num_objects; }
    bool add_object(Game_Object object);    
    void print_objects();

};
```

The invocation of print() is now:

```
void Game_Window::print_objects() {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_objects; i++) {
        objects[i]->print();
    }
}
```

I ran it and it game me no errors.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `Game_Window::objects` is `char**` (pointer to pointer to `char`). Hence `objects[i]` is the `i`<sup>th</sup> pointer, and pointers don't have `print()` methods, which is why `(objects[i])->print();` fails with the described error.

Perhaps you meant to use `print(objects[i]);` instead?